# Laravel: User registration validation error by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using `Ajax` for `Laravel` default `registration` process.

My form is posting successfully. It works fine. But I can't show `Validation` error message by Ajax.

For example: `email` of `users` should be unique. If I don't use `Ajax`. This validation error shows after refreshing page. But in `Ajax` mode, I want to show this error without page refresh.

This is my `JS` code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    type: form.method,
    data: $(form).serialize(),

    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.reg-overlay').show();
    },
    success: function(response){
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function(response){
        console.log(response.responseText);
        var errObj=jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);

        // if(errObj.email)
        //  $('#user-reg-email-err-msg').html(errIcon+' '+errObj.email);
        // if(errObj.roll_no)
        //  $('#user-reg-roll-err-msg').html(errIcon+' '.errObj.roll_no);

        alert(errObj.email); // It appears 'undefined'
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('.reg-overlay').hide();
    }
});
```

Here `alert(errObj.email);` shows `undefined`.
How to fix it?

Comment: what does **console.log(response.responseText)** print?

Comment: {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email has already been taken."],"roll_no":["The roll no has already been taken."]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the format of your **response.responseText** you need to change the way you get your items.

From:

```
errObj.email
```

to:

```
errObj.errors.email
```

The snippet:

```js
var data = '{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email has already been taken."],"roll_no":["The roll no has already been taken."]}}';
var errObj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);

if(errObj.errors.email)
    $('#user-reg-email-err-msg').html(errObj.errors.email[0]);
if(errObj.errors.roll_no)
    $('#user-reg-roll-err-msg').html(errObj.errors.roll_no[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="user-reg-email-err-msg"></div><br/>
<div id="user-reg-roll-err-msg"></div>
```